# SQL Server CTE: How to select the lowest level only

Tags: sql-server-2016

I want to select/display the lowest level of the CTE only. Please help. I am using SQL Server 2016.

```
Create Table Location 
(
    Id int
    Name varchar(20)
    Parent int 
)

Insert into location 
values (1, Location1, null), (2, Location1child, 1), 
       (3, Location1grandchild, 2), (4, Location2, null),
       (5, Location3, null), (6, Locationchild3, 5)
```

I need to display only records 3, 4, 6 which is the lowest level.

Update: I already created the query, but record number 4 didn't display. I am expecting record number 4 to be displayed because the record is the lowest level in the group.

```
With CTE (id, cte_level, cte_name, cte_longname) as 
(
    Select 
        A.ID, 1, 
        cast(A.name as varchar(max)),
        cast(A.name as varchar(max))
    from 
        Location A

    Union All

    Select 
        A.ID, cte_level + 1,
        replicate(' · ' , cte_level ) + cast(A.name as varchar(max)),
        cte.cte_longname + ' . ' +  cast(A.name as varchar(max))
    from 
        Location A
    inner join 
        CTE ON A.Parent = CTE.id
)
select 
    CTE_2.id, 
    CTE_2.cte_longname [name]
    --, A.cte_name [name]           
  from 
      CTE as CTE_1 
inner join 
    CTE as CTE_2 on CTE_1.id = cte_2.id
where 
    CTE_1.cte_level  = 1 
    And CTE_2.cte_level = (Select MAX(CTE.cte_level) From CTE)
order by 
    cte_2.cte_longname
```

Comment: Would you edit in your query/CTE, plus input data and expected results, so people can understand this a bit better? I am not sure it is clear what you mean at present. If you can additionally provide a SQL Fiddle that would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with CTE. Just use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with `IS NULL` check.

```
SELECT P.*
FROM Location P
LEFT OUTER JOIN Location C ON P.Id = C.Parent
WHERE C.Id IS NULL;
```